# ApplicationPool class stopped event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5

I am using the [ApplicationPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690608%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class's  [ApplicationPool.Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691285%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to stop the app pool via C# code. This method stops the app pool, it is fine. But the issue is that I want to detect when the pool has stopped since that method takes some time to make the app pool in stopped state. Is there any event which I should wire to detect whether the app pool has stopped?

Edit: I can't use Global.asax (of site of which I am stopping the app pool) since I am stopping the app pool from another application.

Comment: If you are doing it in asp.net application, then you can handle it in Global.asax - Application_End. Or you are doing it from another application?

Comment: Is the `void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)` on `Global.asax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SpinWait until your application pool is stopped. Something like this:

```
ApplicationPool pool = //your pool here.
pool.Stop();
if (SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => pool.State == ObjectState.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
{
    //The application pool has stopped
}
else
{
    //The application pool did not stop within 30 seconds.
    //An error probably occured.
}
```

You don't have to specify a timeout, however I would strongly recommend it. If you don't, you risk completely blocking the rest of your process.